# Debug Alert: A debugging check in this application has failed

Tags: c, codeblocks

I was running a basic `printf()` function, it ran fine, but every time I close the CMD, a Debug Alert shows up.

Example:

[image: img]

Are there any solutions to fix this?

Comment: The first thing to do when asking a question is to show your code. Please do this, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Assertion, which was hit here just tells you, that the conversion of a value was not free from losing precision. Without the matching code, it will be very hard to help you out of this.
At least it is not a "bad" error, it's just for your information, that the result is not free from losing precision. This can be by design, or really an error.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I appreciate it, now I understand it just a bit more ^^. I've also realised that it happened after creating a new "build" when running the code in Sublime Text, by adding new things to the Path. By not doing this and solely running, compiling, etc... on CodeBlocks, I haven't gotten the problem since